# Display taxonomy terms, child terms and posts in a template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

In a site that I am building I am trying to create a template which will display all my "product" custom post types along with their parent and child taxonomies in some hierarchical structure which is very simple:

Parent taxonomy -> Child taxonomy (if exists) -> posts

I was looking all over the web and surprisingly could not fund an answer..anywhere.

I ended up creating the following code:

```
<?php
// List posts by the terms for a custom taxonomy of any post type

$post_type = 'product';
$tax = 'products';
$tax_args = array(
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
    $tax_terms = get_terms( $tax, $tax_args );
    if ($tax_terms) {
        foreach ($tax_terms  as $tax_term) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'caller_get_posts'=> 1
        );

    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <h4><?php echo $tax_term->name; ?></h4>

                <ul>
                    <?php
                    $my_query->query(array( 'post_type'=>'product', 'showposts'=>'6')); 
                    ?>
                    <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </a>
                        </li>

                    <?php endwhile; // end of loop ?>
                </ul>

        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif; // if have_posts()
        wp_reset_query();

        } // end foreach #tax_terms
    }
    ?>
```

This is almost what I need. I am getting this structure:

**Parent Taxonomy Term**
- Post Type
- Post Type
- Post Type

**Child Taxonomy Term**
- Post Type
- Post Type
- Post Type

Where what I need is this:

**Parent Taxonomy Term**
-- **Child Taxonomy Term**
--- Post Type
--- Post Type
--- Post Type

**Parent Taxonomy Term**
-- **Child Taxonomy Term**
--- Post Type
--- Post Type
--- Post Type

So I understand I need to add something for the child terms but I can't figure out how to do it. thought it is simple but couldn't find any answer

would love to get a help here
thanks